# Getting a compiler warning in the boost C++ libraries

Tags: c++, boost

I am getting this warning when I compile my Visual Studio C++ program:

> Warning    C26495  Variable 'boost::function_base::functor' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6).    Project1    C:\boost\function\function_base.hpp 603

And here is the line in function_base.hpp:

```
public:
    detail::function::vtable_base* vtable;
    mutable detail::function::function_buffer functor;
```

Has anyone ran into this with boost and have you solved it? I tried this, but it gave errors:

```
    mutable detail::function::function_buffer functor{};
```

Minimal reproducible example:

```
#include <boost\\algorithm\\string\\find.hpp>
int main()
{
}
```

This 'minimal reproducible example' gives this error:
Warning C26495  Variable 'boost::function_base::functor' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6).

```
#define BOOST_VERSION 107500
#define BOOST_LIB_VERSION "1_75"
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] and state the version of `boost` you're using.

Comment: For external libraries it is usually makes more sense to disable warnings especially such code style related. e.g. you can place boost `#include` within [pragma warning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/warning?view=msvc-170#push-and-pop) block.

Comment: @dewaffled, thanks, that took care of it. I haven't tried a newer version of boost, but `#pragma` block is more than sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to disable ["external warnings"](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/customized-warning-levels-and-code-analysis-for-external-headers/)

Add your Boost directory to the "External Include Directories" so that `find.hpp` will use the "External Includes" settings. You can then disable code analysis for this specific warning, or drop the warning level to /W3 for similar warnings.

Comment: Thanks. I surrounded the boost .hpp files with a `#pragma` block, as suggested by @dewaffled.